# Proof of Associativity and Commutativity For Multiplication and Addition of Real Numbers.

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility, peano-axioms

This fundamental proof is really bothering me for a long time. I have seen the proofs on proofwiki and other sites but it uses too much mathematical jargon. I would like a nice, intuitive proof using only basic arithmetic axioms and induction.
P.S (If it is not possible to prove this fact for real numbers at least give a proof for natural numbers.
Thank You!

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3507878/intuitive-proof-of-commutativity-of-addition-and-multiplication)

Comment: And see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806738/proof-of-commutativity-of-multiplication-for-natural-numbers-using-peanos-axiom) for commutativity of multiplication

Comment: But Peano axioms are for *naturals* and Induction also works for naturals: it relies on the immediate *successor* of a number $bn$ and in the real domain there is no immediate successor of $r$.

Comment: An see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168914/peano-axioms-and-commutativity-of-addition) for commutativity of addition

Comment: Commutativity for multiplication is quite simple; consider a rectangle of base A and side B. Its area is $\text {length}(A) \times \text {length}(B)$. Now capsize it: the base is now B and A is the new side. What happened to the area ?

Comment: Commutativity for addition is also very simple: put 5 dollars in your pocket and then put 4 dollars. Then empty the pocket and start again: first 4 dollars and then 5 dollars.